# Form submission not working in template file

Tags: forms

While theming form in template file I used `drupal_render` to print selected fields of form. But after hit submit button, data is not saving, means submit button is not working.

I know one solution is to use `drupal_render_children` but it is giving me every child of form, means I'm getting all of the elements of form.

**I don't want form's each and every element.**

Only selected fields should get rendered.

**Any way to print form selected field elements in tpl file with a working submit button?**

Comment: could you please attach your code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more standard way to hide form elements is to make their `#access` property to false , or use hide function or unset function to hide undesired elements . then you can render $form .

for example imagine you are going to hide `$form['details']['name']` , in hook_form_alter you can use this snippet :

```
$form['details']['name']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

or you can hide it from being displayed , using this snippet :

```
hide($form['details']['name']);
```

then you can easily render your form in any place you desire using

```
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('FORM_ID'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can render form specific form elements with the help of `drupal_render`. And in order to make submit button work, render all hidden form items and your submit button will work fine then.

Necessary fields for form submission are:

```
echo drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
echo drupal_render($form['form_token']);
echo drupal_render($form['form_id']);
```

and ofcourse your submit button too.

Answer (score 1):

Please add these four lines after render all your content type or form fields in below sequence.

```
 1. drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);     
 2. drupal_render($form['form_id']); 
 3. drupal_render($form['actions']);  
 4. drupal_render($form['form_token']);
```